# Validation error while updating pages in notion by using the notion javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, notion-api

Here's the error:

Client warn: request fail {
code: 'validation_error',
message: 'body failed validation. Fix one: body.properties.body.id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.properties.body.name should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.properties.body.start should be defined, instead was `undefined`.'
}
body failed validation. Fix one: body.properties.body.id should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.properties.body.name should be defined, instead was `undefined`. body.properties.body.start should be defined, instead was `undefined`

Here's my code :

```js
async function update() {
  const res_2 = await notion.databases.query({ database_id: `${databaseId}` });

  res_2.results.forEach(async (page, index) => {
    let property_id = page.properties.Excerpt.id;
    if (index === 0) {
      try {
        const res_3 = await notion.pages.update({
          page_id: page.id,
          properties: {
            [property_id]: {
              type: "rich_text",
              rich_text: {
                "content": "hey"
              }
            }
          }
        })

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
      }
    }
  })
}
update();
```

I am not getting why there is a body validation error and from where it originated. Any fixes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a little bit of digging, I found out that this error generally occurs when there are missing parameters in the request body. As per the official Notion documentation,

> The request body does not match the schema for the expected parameters. Check the "message" property for more details. https://developers.notion.com/reference/errors

I did not construct the object correctly, and that's why I was getting this error.

The correct construction of `rich_text_object` is as follows:

```js
properties: {
  "Excerpt": {
    "rich_text": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": {
          "content": "hello"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can find more information here : https://developers.notion.com/docs/working-with-page-content#creating-a-page-with-content